# How to deal with repeating player names SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with a dataset from Basketball-Reference.com. I have collected statistics from a single season. However, players get traded throughout the season so I have players who have 2 or 3 rows instead of [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJyHD.png). I want to average these multiple rows into one, so that each player only has one row. So far, I've tried working with the WITH function:

```
WITH `bgdefense.Season2122.pergame2122` AS (
    SELECT 'Nickeil Alexander-Walker' Player, 'SG' Pos, 'TOT' Tm, 2.3 DRB, 0.7 STL, 0.4 BLK UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nickeil Alexander-Walker', 'SG', 'NOP', 2.6, 0.8, 0.4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nickeil Alexander-Walker', 'SG', 'UTA', 1.6, 0.4, 0.3 
)
SELECT 
    Player,
    Pos,
    Tm,
    AVG(DRB),
    AVG(STL),
    AVG(BLK)
FROM `bgdefense.Season2122.pergame2122`
```

When I run this code, I get a not grouped or aggregated [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B59U8.png). So, I'm not really sure where to go from here. I want to keep the player name and position the same while only choosing one team (the one he was on at the start of the season. Then, I want to average the rebounds, steals, etc. I've also had the thought that I should select one row and delete the multiples. I appreciate any input. I am using BigQuery for this.

Comment: I have added my answer. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, whenever we do some aggregations, it is important to group by something. Consider an example of counting average temperature for each US state for entire year. Each state consists of multiple days of data and if you want to compute an average, then you would require to group the `US states` and then count the average. It is similar to how pivot functions operate in some sense in excel.

When you are measuring these averages for each player, you can tweak this query a bit and get your results.

```
WITH `bgdefense.Season2122.pergame2122` AS (
    SELECT 'Nickeil Alexander-Walker' Player, 'SG' Pos, 'TOT' Tm, 2.3 DRB, 0.7 STL, 0.4 BLK UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nickeil Alexander-Walker', 'SG', 'NOP', 2.6, 0.8, 0.4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Nickeil Alexander-Walker', 'SG', 'UTA', 1.6, 0.4, 0.3 
)
SELECT 
    Player,
    Pos,
    AVG(DRB),
    AVG(STL),
    AVG(BLK)
FROM `bgdefense.Season2122.pergame2122`
group by Player, Pos
```

Notice how I have not used the `Tm` column in the `group by` clause. It will depend on your use case what you want to `group by`. My query computes averages of the metrics at `player,position` aggregate level.

Note - I am assuming here that a Tm means team and each player will play across different teams.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me! I realize now that I was getting the error from having Tm under the select option. This is exactly the output I wanted, simply the average of the player's stats across the teams he was on that season.

Comment: After doing this to all the traded players, would my next step be to add these corrected rows and delete the ones I already used? Or is there a way to sort of streamline this process? Once again, thank you! As you can see I'm pretty new to SQL haha

Comment: you are welcome. Can you explain what do you mean by corrected rows? Perhaps an example of input and output can be useful as a new stack overflow question? We can work on streamlining easily but first I need to ensure that I understand what you are trying to do.